# Azure AD B2C authentication hybrid

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I created a B2C AD in my developer account on Azure.
In this environment I have users created in my personal AD, and users in AD B2C (where the user can log in with: twitter and facebook).

I found an ASP.NET project that logs in to these two ADs, but with two types of logins, one for normal AD and one for AD B2C. And from what I've researched, the only way to log in to these two different ADs is this way.

Does anyone know of a way to make a single login in these two ADs?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it now with custom Azure AD B2C policies. It is however quite an advanced scenario.

Using them you could put all authentication behind B2C. User could choose to sign in against your Azure AD or through Twitter or Facebook on the B2C sign-in page instead of your application.

Custom policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom

Documentation on using Azure AD as a provider in B2C: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom

GitHub repo with examples: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies

Comment: Good answer :) Can you also add this link as a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response.
I tried to do this but could not find the settings needed to put Twitter, Google and Microsoft. For Facebook and other AD worked.
I found a post, that Microsoft will soon make available an "Identity Provider" to validate the user in another AD.
For now, I'll put two Sign-in in my application, one for the company's AD and another for the B2C AD.

I am now looking for a way to get the user's profile in AD (Name, First Name, Last Name, Job Title, Departament, ....).

Once this is done, I'm going to make a DEMO and publish it to github, I think this will help a lot of people.